# Reading hdf5 files in F#

Tags: f#, hdf5

Does anyone has code examples reading hdf5 files in F#? I cannot find any examples on SO or google. I tried hdf5.net library but could not get it to work using Python example code.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tried it, there is some sample code available at https://rodhern.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/hdf5-f-to-octave-example/

It's the only example I know of offhand.

Comment: If you look at the post, the example code is only for writing, not for reading.